# Create and use static property on static class in Delphi just like .NET

Tags: delphi, static-methods

I am a .NET developer and very beginner with Delphi.

I want to create a static class and use the properties like this

```
MyVariable := MyStaticClass.MyProperty;
```

I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Class Properties` for this;

```
 type
    TMyClass = class
      strict private
        class var         // Note fields must be declared as class fields
           FRed: Integer;
           FGreen: Integer;
           FBlue: Integer;
        public             // ends the class var block
           class property Red: Integer read FRed write FRed;
           class property Green: Integer read FGreen write FGreen;
           class property Blue: Integer read FBlue write FBlue;
    end
```

In this example, properties named `Red`, `Green` and `Blue` can be used without an object reference. For document; [Class Properties](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Properties_(Delphi)#Class_Properties)

To declare a readonly class (static) property;

```
  TMyClass = class
    private
      const FRedValue:Integer = 10;
    public
      class property Red: Integer read FRedValue;
  end;
```

To use this;

```
aColorVariable := TMyClass.Red;
```

Comment: how can i implement that ?should i create unit ? and i had a lot of errors

Comment: No you do not have to create a new unit, you can declare multiple class in a unit. Just copy the code except type keyword, and paste it in a unit under existing type keyword. But to have a clean code, splitting objects into different units can be a good practice.

Comment: i want to set static data for that and use it on other class . how can i change       [ class property Red: Integer read FRed write FRed;] to  class property myprop: Integer read '10' write '10';

Comment: @sddk You can have multiple ``type`` keywords in one unit!

Comment: @sddk Yes It Must Be ReadOnly

Comment: @DelphiCoder, you are right, i tend to use single one.

Comment: @sddk Still can not use the properties on other forms

Comment: @zolfaghari, use a seperate unit for static class if you want to access to that class from multiple units. to use seperate unit from other forms, have a look at here http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Adding_a_Unit_Reference

Comment: @sddk How can use those property ? is it ststicPropertyValues :class of TMyClass ;

Comment: @sddk compiler says undecleard and i do not know how to declare it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229972/discussion-between-zolfaghari-and-sddk).

Comment: @zolfaghari units are isolated code containers like a namespaces, so to use the code in other units/forms you need to add the unit containing the static class to the `uses` clause. Then you can use these static classes like `TMyClass.StaticProperty`. No need to create the class!

Answer (score 0):

Tips : Unit somhow equals to Class on .NET
Finally i resolve my problem by add those properties to my unit like below :

1. create a unit by right click on the solution name and add > unit
2. declare a const like below :

   const myPropertyName:Integer = 0;
3. add it to your form who you want to use it by

   uses
   YOUR_UNIT_NAME;

After

> interface

section on the form

4. And all i need to do is type my property name who i declared on the unit( myPropertyName)

Comment: No, this is not a static property!

Comment: What you defined is called a global constant.

Comment: All I need is property who I can call everywhere I want on entire solution